# Яремча чи Яремче?

Tags: власні-назви

Неодноразово помічала різні назви населеного пункту Яремча, Яремче.

На сайті https://www.karpaty.info/ua/uk/if/jr/jaremche/ знайшла:

> До 2006 року у вжитку були дві назви міста — Яремча і Яремче, перша з яких з'явилася у 20-х роках ХХ ст. завдяки польським урядовцям, а потім була зафіксована радянськими. Первісну назву Яремче було уточнено рішенням Верховної Ради.

Рішення ВР є актуальним на сьогодні?

Comment: відредагувала запитання. не була впевнена в тому, що рішенням є актуальним і сьогодні. до того ж, за останні роки зустрічала обидва варіанти. тому і запитую

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Коротко:

На сьогодні правильно писати **Яремче**.

#### Довші дослідки й пояснення:

З [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B5)

> Яре́мче (? —2006 — Яремча) — місто обласного підпорядкування в
>   Україні, Івано-Франківській області.

На сайті [Mista.ua](http://mistaua.com/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B5) знаходимо назву ***Яремче***

> Колишня назва: **Яремча** а з 2006 року **Яремче**

Хоча в [Словнику відмінків](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B0) вказано **Яремча**, не варто брати до уваги адже виданий він раніше ніж змінили назву.

[image]

[Згідно з постановою ВРУ "Про уточнення найменування міста Яремча Івано-Франківської області "](http://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/480-v)

> Уточнити найменування    міста    Яремча   Івано-Франківської  області
>   - на Яремче.

Отже, правильно писати ***Яремче***, хоча в розмові можна почути обидва варіанти.

Answer (score 2):

Як Ви самі зазначили в запитанні, у 2006 назву міста було змінено з *Яремча* на *Яремче* (ймовірно, повернули історично початкову назву, хоча подробиці не переглядав).

І досі офіційною назвою залишається **Яремче** (в цьому можна переконатися, наприклад, зробивши [пошук різних варіантів назви на сайтах домену .gov.ua](//www.google.com/search?q=(%22%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B0%22+OR+%22%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B5%22)+site:gov.ua); зокрема на [сторінці сайту Головного управління статистики в Івано-Франківській області](http://www.ifstat.gov.ua/rn/m-JAREMCHE.htm), що наразі востаннє оновлювалася у вересні 2018 й містить дані до липня 2018, використовується назва *Яремче*).